# Oracle APEX - APP_USER Substitution string

Tags: oracle-apex

Hello everyone i need your help. I need the user's first name and last name to be displayed instead of the apex login. I found the following code, maybe i'm writing it in the wrong place. I don't know, i write it to the 9999  password page and create a process there

declare
v_user_name varchar2 (20);
v_first_name varchar2 (20);

begin

select username, first_name

into v_user_name, v_first_name

from all_users

where username = :APP_USER;

htp.prn(v_user_name || ' ' || v_first_name);

end;

Comment: You said you need help. With what, exactly? You posted some code, but never said what happened. Is there any error? If so, which one? Does user, whose username is equal to what APP_USER returns, exist in ALL_USERS? Post all info you think that might help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

I would not touch APP_USER. That is the built-in variable that contains the login username. I'm assuming that by "to be displayed instead of the login", you are referring to the username displayed in the top right of your apex screen. That is defined in the navigation bar:

[image]

Good news... you can change this.

1. Create a new application item called G_FULL_NAME (shared components > application items)
2. Create a new application computation on G_FULL_NAME, with computation point "After Authentication" and type "SQL Query (return single value)" and source :

```
select username || ' ' || first_name
from all_users
where username = :APP_USER
```

3. In the navigation bar entry, change `&APP_USER.` to `&G_FULL_NAME.`

Note 1: that when testing this it might be helpful to set the computation point of the computation in step 2 to "Before Header", else you have to log in/out every time. When it works, set it to "After authentication"

Note 2: `ALL_USERS` is probably not the correct table to get this information from - that is a list of database schemas you are able to see. Use the public synonym  APEX_WORKSPACE_APEX_USERS as @Scott mentioned (avoid using the internal FND_ tables)

Comment: Thank you so much! I used another table from APEX_200200 WWV_FLOW_FND_USER and it worked))

Comment: I was going to add that it would be odd to find the APP_USER record in ALL_USERS, unless you're using DB Authentication, which I would posit is rare.

Comment: And you should use the APEX dictionary view APEX_WORKSPACE_APEX_USERS instead of going direct

Comment: @Scott thanks - good point. I focused on getting another value than APP_USER displayed and ignored the source of the info. Have updated my answer.